# linux replace string with another string

Tags: linux, string, bash, replace, sed

I want to replace a string in a file.
I have a textfile which looks like this: id#string.

```
123456#some new string
234567#some other new string
345678#still some other new string
```

and then I have alot of folders based on the id of the textfile.

so now I want to replace the string in a textfile

```
{"fields":[{"t":"B","v":"false or true","n":"SomeText"},{"t":"S","v":"","n":"Keywords"},{"t":"S","v":"","n":"Author"},{"t":"S","v":"","n":"SomeText"},{"t":"S","v":"THI$ is THE old §TRING I want to REPLACE","n":"SomeText"},{"t":"S","v":"","n":"SomeText"},{"t":"A","n":"SomeText"},{"t":"A","v":"SomeInt","n":"SomeText"}]}
```

but i dont know how to do this since the newstring and or oldstring may contain additional characters

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER=`echo 123456#string | cut -d# -f1`
NEWSTRING=`echo 123456#string | cut -d# -f2`
sed -i ??? $FOLDER/filename.txt
```

thanks for your help

Comment: How are you supposed to recognize the _old_ string to replace with a _new_ string? Is the _old_ string always the same `THI$ is THE old §TRING I want to REPLACE`?

Comment: hi james, the new string is stored at a textfile ID#STRING I would reset a variable in a for-loop but i can't figure out how to replace it

Comment: I understand that the _new_ string is in the first file. Which _old_ string do I replace with the _new_ string?

Comment: oh, it's at the first comment. scroll to the right: "THI$ is THE old §TRING I want to REPLACE"

Comment: and no it's not always the same it's always different

Comment: So, how are we supposed to know which string to replace?

Comment: maybe by using awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of the issue is not clear what should be engaged and what replaced, but maybe you need is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# t1 file contains your strings
#

ROW='{"fields":[{"t":"B","v":"false or true","n":"SomeText"},{"t":"S","v":"","n":"Keywords"},{"t":"S","v":"","n":"Aut
IFS=$'\n'
for S in $(cat ./t1); do
    F=$(echo $S | awk -F# '{print $1}')
    N=$(echo $S | awk -F# '{print $2}')
    if [ -z "$N" ]; then continue; fi
    NROW=$(echo ${ROW/THIS is THE old STRING I want to REPLACE/$S})
    NROW=$(echo ${NROW/Keywords/$N})
    NROW=$(echo ${NROW/false or true/$F})
    #mkdir $F
    #echo $NROW >> file.json
    echo $NROW 
done
```